# QML: "NumberAnimation with foo" syntax - what does it mean?

Tags: qt, syntax, qml, keyword, qtquick2

I started writing a NumberAnimation declaration in Qt Creator and got several things in an autocomplete box. One of them was "NumberAnimation with target". Does that mean there is syntax like this:

```
NumberAnimation with foo {
    // ...
}
```

I think I have also seen this syntax used before, but I don't remember what it does, and neither of these two Qt doc pages: [[1]](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlreference.html) [[2]](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-basics.html) seem to mention it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The auto completion suggestion that you got was for one of Creator's built-in [snippets](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-completing-code.html#completing-code-snippets). If you selected the option (by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, for example), you'll get this code:

```
NumberAnimation {
    target: object
    property: "name"
    duration: 200
    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
}
```

You can also see a preview of the code that it will expand to in a tooltip to the right of the auto completion popup.

> I think I have also seen this syntax used before [...]

The syntax you're thinking of is probably [`<Animation> on <Property>`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-statesanimations-animations.html#using-predefined-targets-and-properties):

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: rect
    width: 100; height: 100
    color: "red"

    PropertyAnimation on x { to: 100 }
    PropertyAnimation on y { to: 100 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the "number animation with target" snippet generates the following stub:

```
  NumberAnimation {
    target: object
    property: "name"
    duration: 200
    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
  }
```

IMO it doesn't imply there is a `with` format of use. Furthermore, using `with` actually results in a syntax error. So it doesn't look like it is a thing.